# filtering return status of new function

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have this function:**

```
   offerStatus: function() {
        var status = this.get('active');
        return (status) ? 'ACTIVE': 'INACTIVE' ;
    },
```

**In relation to:**

```
<tr class="borderless">
    <td><%=offer.offerType()%>
    </td>
    <td><%=offer.offerStart()%> - <%=offer.offerEnd()%></td>
    <td><%=offer.getValidLocations()%></td>
    <td><%=offer.offerStatus()%></td> <!-- test. revert back to offerStatus if no go -->
    <td><%=offer.launchDay()%></td>
</tr>
```

**I would like to add a way to ONLY display or return 'Active' status** for one/this page.

I have tried adding the below function in attempt to create an 'activeStatus' but it did not work.

```
activeStatus: function() {
    var status = this.get('active');
    return (status) ? 'ACTIVE': 'ACTIVE' ;
}, // test didn't work - but instead, killed the display of anything.
```

Currently page in question outputs.

*Active > Inactive* in vertical -- which is fine; but I want only 'Active' to display; but I don't want to kill the functionality in complete entirety because in some cases; I will want to keep them both displaying.

Comment: Why is this a bad question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if(offer.offerStatus() === 'ACTIVE') { %>
<tr class="borderless">
    <td><%=offer.offerType()%>
    </td>
    <td><%=offer.offerStart()%> - <%=offer.offerEnd()%></td>
    <td><%=offer.getValidLocations()%></td>
    <td><%=offer.offerStatus()%></td> <!-- test. revert back to offerStatus if no go -->
    <td><%=offer.launchDay()%></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

I am assuming this is EJS?  Either way, something like this should work.